# Tokenize Review wise for sentiment analysis

Tags: nlp, data-science, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, tfidfvectorizer

In this Amazon dataset I've Product_Description , Product_Type & Sentiment column where I want to build classification model. keeping Product_Description & Product_Type as X and Sentiment as Y. but i receive few error still not able to find the solution. I want the sentence itself to be tokenize for tfidf not different words.

```
> amazon.head()
```

[Link to data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czg9l.png)

```
> `Z = amazon["Product_Description"]
> Y = amazon["Sentiment"]
> tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
> tf = pd.DataFrame(tfidf.fit_transform(Z),columns = ["Product_Description"])
> X = pd.concat((tf,amazon["Product_Type"]),axis = 1)
> X.drop(X[X["Product_Description"].isnull()].index, inplace = True)
> test_size = 0.2
> seed = 45
> X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = test_size, random_state = seed)
> X_train.shape,X_test.shape # [((5081, 2), (1271, 2))] is the output
> model = LogisticRegression(max_iter = 500)
> 
> rfe = RFE(model, n_features_to_select = 2)
> fit = rfe.fit(X, Y)
> 
> fit.n_features_
> fit.support_
> fit.ranking_`
```

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'csr_matrix'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [57], in <cell line: 7>()
      4 model = LogisticRegression(max_iter = 500)
      6 rfe = RFE(model, n_features_to_select = 2)
----> 7 fit = rfe.fit(X, Y)
      9 fit.n_features_
     10 fit.support_
```ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
````

​

Comment: The error is probably caused by this concatenation `X = pd.concat((tf,amazon["Product_Type"]),axis = 1)`. In case you want to use `amazon["Product_Type"]` in the features, you need to encode it of course. Otherwise don't concatenate it, this is simpler.